# BB 10 Cascades Internet Check

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to check the Internet Connection If I get Socket Error. I am proceeding like this,

```
void Client::socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError) {
   HttpPost("https://www.google.co.in/");
}

void Client::HttpPost(QString URL ) {

    QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest();
    request.setUrl(QUrl(URL));

    QNetworkAccessManager *mNetworkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    bool result = connect(mNetworkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                          this, SLOT(HttpResponse(QNetworkReply *)));

    mNetworkAccessManager->get(request);
    qDebug() << "::: Client.cpp  Request made to Service :::";
}

void Client::HttpResponse(QNetworkReply* reply) {

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "\n  Internet Ok **********";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "\n No Internet **********" << reply->errorString();
        showDialog("No Inernet");
    }
}
```

and I am connecting to Signals and Slots like

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
        this, SLOT(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

But some times I am getting "No Internet Dialog " Even If wi-fi Is Available. Why ?

---

Method 2:

```
// this method will return true If Net is available false other wise
// but even this is return false some times even Wi fi signal is Available 

bool Client::isNetworkAvailable() {
    bool isFound = false;
    QNetworkConfigurationManager netMgr;
    QList<QNetworkConfiguration> mNetList = netMgr.allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active);

    if (mNetList.count() > 0) {
            if (netMgr.isOnline()) {
                isFound = true;
            }
    }
    qDebug() << "\n ************** isNetworkAvailable:::" << isFound;
    return isFound;
}
```

Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes? You got it once or twice? Can you reliably reproduce the issue "some times"? Are you sure it was not a temporary outage?

Comment: I mean It is not showing often "No Internet Dialog " Even If wi-fi Is Available.

Comment: Please find the second method that I have tried. but not working

Comment: @Sharath Any solution you found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network check snippet seems a bit too complicated. You could simply just call the following method:

> [bool QNetworkConfigurationManager::isOnline () const](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#isOnline)
>
> Returns true if the system is considered to be connected to another device via an active network interface; otherwise returns false.

If this does not work for someone, it very likely means that the internet connection is unreliably, especially if it does not work randomly.

Comment: it giving false always even if I am connected to network

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
NetworkAccessibility QNetworkAccessManager::networkAccessible ()
```

> networkAccessible : NetworkAccessibility
>
> This property holds whether the network is currently accessible via
>   this network access manager.
>
> If the network is not accessible the network access manager will not
>   process any new network requests, all such requests will fail with an
>   error. Requests with URLs with the file:// scheme will still be
>   processed.